# How do I link an .svg file in my HTML and retain the ability to affect "currentColor" property?

Tags: html, svg

I created and inserted a SVG markup into my HTML code and use the attribute `fill="currentColor"` to grab the current text color. And it works like a charm.

for instance:

```
<svg version="1.0" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
   <circle fill="currentColor" cx="10" cy="10" r="10 />
</svg>
```

So I would like to move the content to separeted files.

I Tried: `<img src="myFile.svg" />` and `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="myFile.svg">` but both of them fills all the `currentColor` shapes with black instead of the current text color.

How do I link an .svg file in my HTML and retain the ability to affect "currentColor" property?

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use img or object tag for loading svg file because you can't do custom styling on it.
There are a couple of approaches to load svg file wisely in the HTML.

1. Put the svg file into public directory and use ajax request

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var svg = xhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById('myicon').innerHTML = svg;
  }
};

xhttp.open('GET', '/myFile.svg', true);
xhttp.send();
```

```html
<i id="myicon">
  <!-- Put svg content here -->
</i>
```

You can create a reusable svg component if you tackle SPA frameworks like Angular or React.

2. If you use ES6 or Typescript, use svg loader.

Put the icon into somewhere under the `src` folder which webpack svg loader can access to. And configure svg webpack loader in your project then you can import svg file like the following:

```js
import svg from './myFile.svg';
```

You can use whatever you like.